# Best-value in-ear earphones with volume control?

Tags: earphones

I'm looking for a wired in-ear earphones that has volume control and is compatible with iPhone 6 and later. I'm aware that the prices of earphones with volume control can shoot up really quickly, so would appreciate best-value recommendations. Thanks.

Comment: Inline software volume control buttons, or an actual hardware knob? Also, iPhone 6 and **later** seems to imply Lightning connector; is that what you want, or do you want a standard headphone jack?

Comment: @JMY1000 Id like a pair of earrings with physical volume control buttons on them that work with iPhone 6 or later. This is because some earphones seem to only work with certain iPhone generations and not others

Comment: Gotcha. Do you want ones that use the Lighting connector or the standard 3.5mm headphone jack?

Comment: Probably the one that uses the 3.5mm jack. I presume that's what most iPhones have?

Comment: The iPhone 7 and later don't have a headphone jack.